# How do I create the formula for calculate the damage of a skill

Tags: mathematics, character, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the output damage of a skill. The skill can go up from level 1 to 100, it can scale with own levels and the attack of the character.

Here some parameters

[image]

Edit:

I need a formula for determine the amount of damage that a skill or ability can do.

I have some data that I don't have create myself, but I just taken from a game.

A character can grow up from lv 1 to 100, and he has a set of skills.

Every skill can go up from lv 1 to (current level of the character)

The skill damage is linear but influenced of character's attack, so more attack the character has and more damage can do the skill.

A character that we call John has the follow parameters

Max stats that John can reach

- Level 100
- Attack 7337
- Skill damage (lv 100) 16574

Minimum stats

- Level 1
- Attack 71
- Skill damage (lv 1) 479

The current stats of John

- Level 13
- Attack 202
- Skill damage (lv 13) 805

When the skill was a previous level

- Level 13
- Attack 202
- Skill damage (lv 12) 788

In theory the skill damage should get 7 points for level, of course with the current amount of John's attack, but is linear.

What I'm trying to do is get the basic damage of a skill plus the correct multiplier

Comment: Uh...you clearly have some math already, so, what's the problem?

Comment: Depending on how you made these parameters, create a formula for it. How did you initially make them? An example is: Skill A does 5 damage per level, so the formula is "damage = level* 5", obviously yours is more complicated, but you are the one that made it, so you are the one that knows the logic behind it.

Comment: Are you asking us to reverse-engineer a formula to approximate the table of values you included above? If so, explaining your reasoning in choosing those numbers might help us get up to speed on the problem. Or, if you want a formula that doesn't necessarily match those values, then you'll need to provide additional criteria which we can use to decide whether any particular formula is a good or bad solution to this problem.

Comment: You can literally invent a formula for this. There's no right answer for this.

Comment: Do I understand that you're trying to copy the formulas used by an existing game, instead of your own original design? I hope you can understand why professional game developers might have ethical qualms about assisting with this, as it could be used to make unauthorized clones of someone else's hard work creating the original game. To put us at ease, can you tell us a bit more about why you need to copy this game exactly, and whether you've reached out to the original creators for their support?